# PhalconPHP find function

Tags: php, phalcon

today my question is more about style than about programming...

I'm starting with PhalconPHP and I'm very surprised by its power, but there's a little trouble when I do use the find function to get all the results.

When I do this

```
$categories = Category::find('ORDER BY name DESC');
```

I get a mysql error about misspelling (because it assumes I want use a WHERE), so I have to do this:

```
$categories = Category::find('1=1 ORDER BY name DESC');
```

Which I consider tricky and absurd, there's a way to do what I want with no "tricks"?

Comment: When find() only has one argument, it assumes that argument is a condition, not an order clause.

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array as an argument for `find()`, e.g.:

```
Category::find(array('order'=>'name DESC', 'limit'=>10));
```